# Combination/Permutation formula for the question below

Tags: combinatorics

So there is this question in my assignment. 12 houses arranged in a row, A B C D E F G H I J K L. 3 houses are selected. How many combinations are there where the houses are side by side each other, e.g. A B C, B C D, C D E, etc..

**I know the answer is 10 by listing it out manually**. But is it possible to make a combination/permutation formula to solve the question? If so, what is it? If no, why not?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the problem statement, I don't quite get what you mean by houses being adjacent to eachother? It would be helpful if you provided the list of $10$ combinations (as $10$ is a small number). This will not only allow us to see your work, but also give us a better idea of what the problem is asking for.

Comment: Yes, so the houses are lined in a straight row: A is beside B; B is beside A and C; C is beside B and D and so on. It is asking how many combinations are there that satisfies the condition, should 3 houses be chosen at random, are adjacent/beside one another. The list of combinations that I got are: A B C, B C D, C D E, D E F, E F G, F G H, G H I, H I J, I J K and J K L. Total of 10 possible simple events.

Comment: Just choose the house that will be in the middle of your three side by side houses. Obviously all house but at the ends of the line can be chosen. $\binom{10}{1}=10$. Any simple problem can be solved in a more complicated way, but why?

Answer (score 1):

A better way is as below:

Remove the labels and remove three unlabeled houses.

Now there are $9$ unlabeled houses in a row *and $10$ spaces* where the group of the three houses removed can be put in

$- H - H - H - H - H - H - H -H - H-$

**Now** label the houses. Thus you have obtained every possible combination of three adjoining houses, which is $10$

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is just simple counting by listing.

If you insist on treating it mathematically, we can do the following:-

Tie ABC togenther as one unit (ie. (ABC)). There are 12 -3 + 1 units to choose from. Among these 10 units, only one unit (which is ABC) meets our requirement. This means there is only one way.

Repeat the above for (BCD) and all the way till (JKL)

Comment: So, there is no possible way for a combination/permutation formula( nCr/nPr ) to be used right? Im obsessed because these kind of qn are often masked by tricky word play, and I suck at english.

Comment: The other thing I can thinlk of is OR (i.e. [ABC] or [BCD] or ..... ) . In probability, the "OR" is a "+" if the items are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhhhh, okay i think i get it. So basically i shouldn't use the combinations/permutations formula and should instead just add the probability of individual simple events happening on their own? But I have a new qn then. What if there are thousands of houses lined in a row? How do i do it then?

Comment: Nvm, i think its just doing an n-2 thing because A and the nth letter cant form an ABC (A would form a {blank}, A, B and the nth would form a n-1, n, {blank} set). Thank you so much, I understand now.